# Why does this table not work in a beamer presentation?

Tags: tables, beamer

I have the following table and would like to insert in beamer presentation but having errors anytime I run the code. I would be very grateful if you can assist me. Thank you.

```
%-------------------Stochastic Frontier Production: Wheat-------------------------------------%
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\small
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{Stochastic Frontier Production: Wheat}
\begin{tabular}{l c c c}
\hline\hline 
\textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Model 1} & \textbf{Model 2} & \textbf{Model 3}\\ \hline
Wheat land      &       0.484\sym{***}&       0.418\sym{***}&       0.375\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0419)         &    (0.0384)         &    (0.0379)         \\

Labor          &       0.197\sym{***}&       0.182\sym{***}&       0.182\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0500)         &    (0.0445)         &    (0.0436)         \\

Number of oxen          &       0.290\sym{***}&       0.187\sym{**} &       0.229\sym{**} \\
                    &    (0.0756)         &    (0.0699)         &    (0.0701)         \\

Capital       &      0.0822\sym{***}&      0.0267         &      0.0231         \\
                    &    (0.0241)         &    (0.0236)         &    (0.0237)         \\

Soil fertility        &                     &     -0.0415         &     -0.0652         \\
                    &                     &    (0.0659)         &    (0.0650)         \\

Land slope         &                     &    -0.00921         &   -0.000967         \\
                    &                     &     (0.106)         &     (0.105)         \\

Amhara Region       &                     &       0.807\sym{*}  &       2.228\sym{***}\\
                    &                     &     (0.329)         &     (0.316)         \\

Oromia Region       &                     &       1.203\sym{***}&       2.941\sym{***}\\
                    &                     &     (0.248)         &     (0.305)         \\

SNNPR Region        &                     &       0.192         &       2.921\sym{***}\\
                    &                     &     (0.301)         &     (0.493)         \\

Year 2009         &                     &      -0.628\sym{**} &      -0.775\sym{***}\\
                    &                     &     (0.236)         &     (0.126)         \\

Wheat season min. temperature       &                     &       0.465\sym{***}&                     \\
                    &                     &    (0.0833)         &                     \\

Wheat season max. temperature      &                     &      -0.610\sym{***}&                     \\
                    &                     &    (0.0951)         &                     \\

Wheat season rainfall      &                     &      -0.375\sym{***}&                     \\
                    &                     &    (0.0832)         &                     \\

Wheat season rainfall  lagged one year    &                     &      0.0456         &                     \\
                    &                     &    (0.0312)         &                     \\

Wheat season rainfall  lagged two years      &                     &       0.209\sym{***}&                     \\
                    &                     &    (0.0468)         &                     \\

Annual rainfall     &                     &                     &      -0.289\sym{**} \\
                    &                     &                     &    (0.0932)         \\

Annual max. temperature   &                     &                     &      -1.228\sym{***}\\
                    &                     &                     &     (0.158)         \\

Annual min. temperature       &                     &                     &       1.073\sym{***}\\
                    &                     &                     &     (0.141)         \\

Constant            &       5.730\sym{***}&       15.43\sym{***}&       24.31\sym{***}\\
                    &     (0.194)         &     (1.667)         &     (2.582)         \\

$\sigma^2$                &        459.0885             &       226.4106               &         228.8249             \\

                    & (1383.531)          &   (398.8891)    &       (389.8677)       \\

$\gamma$              &       0.999               &       0.998          &          0.999               \\

                    &  (0.0028)        &    (0.0027)       &    (0.0025)        \\

Log-likelihood&-661.1631 &-565.6518 &-563.6243 \\
Observations        &         538         &         538         &         538         \\
\bottomrule
 \multicolumn{4}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses ***\(p<0.01\), ** \(p<0.05\), *\(p<0.1\)}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
%------- End LaTeX code -------%
```

Comment: I edited the title because it was very misleading.  Surely, what you experience is not what a software developer understands as a regression.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: "Why does this table not fit inside a `beamer` frame?" That would be primarily because the table has more than twice as many rows as will fit in a `beamer` frame, assuming you're not willing to reduce the font size so drastically as to make the material undecipherable. As the table is set up currently, it barely fits in a portrait-mode page. How/why do you expect it to fit in a `beamer` frame, which uses landscape mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have `\def`initions inside your frame - move it to the preamble.

This removes the error, but good luck fitting an elephant into a suitcase - not every layout that works in a normal document is suitable for a presentation. Furthermore for the document where you took the table from: I would suggest to align the numbers by their decimal point - this is easy to using the `siunitx` package.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[shrink=40]
%-------------------Stochastic Frontier Production: Wheat-------------------------------------%
\begin{table}\centering
\small
\caption{Stochastic Frontier Production: Wheat}
\begin{tabular}{l c c c}
\hline\hline 
\textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Model 1} & \textbf{Model 2} & \textbf{Model 3}\\ \hline
Wheat land      &       0.484\sym{***}&       0.418\sym{***}&       0.375\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0419)         &    (0.0384)         &    (0.0379)         \\

Labor          &       0.197\sym{***}&       0.182\sym{***}&       0.182\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0500)         &    (0.0445)         &    (0.0436)         \\

Number of oxen          &       0.290\sym{***}&       0.187\sym{**} &       0.229\sym{**} \\
                    &    (0.0756)         &    (0.0699)         &    (0.0701)         \\

Capital       &      0.0822\sym{***}&      0.0267         &      0.0231         \\
                    &    (0.0241)         &    (0.0236)         &    (0.0237)         \\

Soil fertility        &                     &     -0.0415         &     -0.0652         \\
                    &                     &    (0.0659)         &    (0.0650)         \\

Land slope         &                     &    -0.00921         &   -0.000967         \\
                    &                     &     (0.106)         &     (0.105)         \\

Amhara Region       &                     &       0.807\sym{*}  &       2.228\sym{***}\\
                    &                     &     (0.329)         &     (0.316)         \\

Oromia Region       &                     &       1.203\sym{***}&       2.941\sym{***}\\
                    &                     &     (0.248)         &     (0.305)         \\

SNNPR Region        &                     &       0.192         &       2.921\sym{***}\\
                    &                     &     (0.301)         &     (0.493)         \\

Year 2009         &                     &      -0.628\sym{**} &      -0.775\sym{***}\\
                    &                     &     (0.236)         &     (0.126)         \\

Wheat season min. temperature       &                     &       0.465\sym{***}&                     \\
                    &                     &    (0.0833)         &                     \\

Wheat season max. temperature      &                     &      -0.610\sym{***}&                     \\
                    &                     &    (0.0951)         &                     \\

Wheat season rainfall      &                     &      -0.375\sym{***}&                     \\
                    &                     &    (0.0832)         &                     \\

Wheat season rainfall  lagged one year    &                     &      0.0456         &                     \\
                    &                     &    (0.0312)         &                     \\

Wheat season rainfall  lagged two years      &                     &       0.209\sym{***}&                     \\
                    &                     &    (0.0468)         &                     \\

Annual rainfall     &                     &                     &      -0.289\sym{**} \\
                    &                     &                     &    (0.0932)         \\

Annual max. temperature   &                     &                     &      -1.228\sym{***}\\
                    &                     &                     &     (0.158)         \\

Annual min. temperature       &                     &                     &       1.073\sym{***}\\
                    &                     &                     &     (0.141)         \\

Constant            &       5.730\sym{***}&       15.43\sym{***}&       24.31\sym{***}\\
                    &     (0.194)         &     (1.667)         &     (2.582)         \\

$\sigma^2$                &        459.0885             &       226.4106               &         228.8249             \\

                    & (1383.531)          &   (398.8891)    &       (389.8677)       \\

$\gamma$              &       0.999               &       0.998          &          0.999               \\

                    &  (0.0028)        &    (0.0027)       &    (0.0025)        \\

Log-likelihood&-661.1631 &-565.6518 &-563.6243 \\
Observations        &         538         &         538         &         538         \\
\bottomrule
 \multicolumn{4}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses ***\(p<0.01\), ** \(p<0.05\), *\(p<0.1\)}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
%------- End LaTeX code -------%

\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @samcaster, nice work, however, such a table on the presentation would never make an impression on me ... I would rather see a bar chart diagram :)

Comment: @samcaster, thanks for the help. Also, I will align the numbers as you suggested. Finally, I will not put all the variables in the frame. Once again thanks!

Comment: OK. I will do that.

Answer (score -2):

The error stems from use of \bottomrule (perhaps because table is already outside margin by that stage). remove it and it works.

Comment: `\bottomrule` comes from the booktabs package, the question should have mentioned that and provided a real example, but that is unlikely to be the error that is being asked about.

Comment: the document compiles correctly without \bottomrule. that's all i am saying.

Comment: In a class like `article`, then yes, it does work, but it doesn't work inside a `frame` environment in a `beamer` document.